# Returning queried rows from a generic repository

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've implemented (or "borrowed" off the web!) a generic repository within my project and now currently stuck with how to access certain records via this repository.

Sample data:

```
ID  | Policy ID     |   History ID  | Policy name
1   |   1           |    0          | Test
2   |   1           |    1          | Test
3   |   2           |    0          | Test1
4   |   2           |    1          | Test1
```

What I need is the records that have the greatest history ID, so Policy ID 1 and 2 will come out with History ID 2 (Id's 2 and 4).

My generic repository code is as follows:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Now, I understand that I should be using the filter parameter on this function, but how in my scenario, is it even possible? I guess I'd have to use a Grouping method.

My code for calling is (if it helps at all):

```
var policies = _policy.Get();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to know the generic type before you can do anything specific linq stuff like grouping. For example, if you do not know the type than you cannot specify any properties on which to group.